# Add atributes to HTML tags without class or id using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, class, tags

This is my HTML codes.

```
<ul id="abc">

<li>
<a title="1" href="#">1</a>
</li>

<li>
<a title="2" href="#">1</a>
</li>

 <li>
 <a title="3" href="#">1</a>
 </li>

</ul>
```

i want to add href atributes to each anchor tags using jquery. but there is no id or classes. how this possible. can we use these titles. ie set atributes where title=1 or title=2 etc? Please help? Thanks...

Comment: is it the same links to all the `a` s ??

Comment: all links are different...

Comment: This question depends upon how, precisely, you want to identify the elements you wish to target.

Comment: yes. i want to target those anchor tags using titles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to get the anchor tags with the id abc and use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#abc a').attr('href', 'someurl');
```

You can use attribute selector to get element by title.

```
$('a[title=1]').attr("href","url");
```

If your title are number and are in sequence you can use filter

```
$('#abc a').filter(function(){
      return parseInt(this.title) < 4;
}).attr("href","url");
```

Comment: how can we specify each a tags using titles

Answer (score 1):

You can select specific anchor tags using the attribute equals selector.

```
$('a[title=1]').attr("href","url") // or use .prop() for later versions of jQuery
```

Or, if you want to select all anchor tags in the `<ul>` list, use @Adil 's answer.

Comment: I don't think .prop() will replace .attr() in this case. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5884994/1497042